# Using the @use decorator in bonobo

Tags: python, python-decorators, bonobo-etl

In the bonobo documentation, they have the following example for configuring a service dependency:

```
from bonobo.config import use
@use('orders_database')
def select_all(database):
yield from database.query('SELECT * FROM foo;')
```

I tried to do something similar, and got an error.  Here is a very simplified version of my script:

```
import bonobo
from bonobo.config import use
from ftplib import FTP

def get_services(**options):
    ftp_1 =  FTP('ftp.gnu.org')
    ftp_1.login()
    ftp_1.cwd('gnu/emacs')
    return{
        'ftp1': ftp_1,
    }

@use('ftp1')
def listen_for_file(ftp):
    test = ftp.nlst('README.olderversions')
    if test:
        print( 'Found file')
        return True
    else:
        print('File not found in ftp')
        return False

def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.add_chain(listen_for_file)
    return graph

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = bonobo.get_argument_parser()
    with bonobo.parse_args(parser) as options:
        bonobo.run(get_graph(**options), services=get_services(**options))
```

If I try to run this, I get the following error:

> CRITICAL:bonobo.execution.contexts.base:<NodeExecutionContext(+listen_for_file) in=1 err=1>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\mfrants\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bonobo\config\processors.py", line 102, in **call**
> bound = self._bind(_input)
> File "C:\Users\mfrants\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bonobo\config\processors.py", line 89, in _bind
> return bind(*self.args, *_input, **self.kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\mfrants\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\inspect.py", line 3015, in bind
> return args[0]._bind(args[1:], kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\mfrants\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\inspect.py", line 2930, in _bind
> raise TypeError(msg) from None
> TypeError: missing a required argument: 'ftp'

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\mfrants\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bonobo\execution\contexts\node.py", line 102, in loop
> self.step()
> File "C:\Users\mfrants\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bonobo\execution\contexts\node.py", line 129, in step
> results = self._stack(input_bag)
> File "C:\Users\mfrants\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bonobo\config\processors.py", line 114, in **call**
> ) from exc
> bonobo.errors.UnrecoverableTypeError: Input of <function listen_for_file at 0x000002A591047F78> does not bind to the node signature.
> Args: ()
> Input: ()
> Kwargs: {'ftp1': <ftplib.FTP object at 0x000002A5910CF708>}
> Signature: (ftp)

The only way I can get it to run is if I change ftp to ftp1 in the listen_for_file function.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: > The only way I can get it to run is if I change ftp to ftp1 in the listen_for_file function.

Yes, this sounds make sense to me. Because the reference name should be the same from what I'm thinking.

Comment: @FonyLew, so is it working as intended, then?  Because the example I quoted from the documentation page has different names ('orders_database' in the use decorator and 'database' in the function definition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bonobo is strict about variable naming - although it shouldn't be.

To use `config.use`, it is better to use the exact service name in function signature, and keep it as the last parameter.

To change the actual service provider you want to use, you need to change the map in your `get_services` function.

```
import bonobo
from bonobo.config import use
from ftplib import FTP

def get_services(**options):
    ftp_1 =  FTP(options.get('ftp_server') or 'ftp.gnu.org')
    ftp_1.login()
    ftp_1.cwd('gnu/emacs')
    return{
        'ftp': ftp_1,
    }

@use('ftp')
def listen_for_file(ftp):
    test = ftp.nlst('README.olderversions')
    if test:
        print( 'Found file')
        return True
    else:
        print('File not found in ftp')
        return False

def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.add_chain(listen_for_file)
    return graph

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = bonobo.get_argument_parser()
    parser.add('--ftp_server')
    with bonobo.parse_args(parser) as options:
        bonobo.run(get_graph(**options), services=get_services(**options))
```

Comment: Thank you, @PyGuy, this does what I want it to do.